# How to select 2 distinct columns and count one of them

Tags: mysql, sql

Ok so I'm trying to do the following. I have a table that has questions and answers. I'm trying to figure out how many answers I have of each answer on each question.

```
Question                     Answer
--------                     ------
What is your favorite color? Blue
What is your favorite color? Red
What is your favorite color? Blue
What is your age?            12
What is your age?            15
```

Now what I want is results (query) to output something like this:

```
What is your favorite color? Blue 2
What is your favorite color? Red 1
What is your age? 12 1
What is your age? 15 1
```

OR

```
What is your favorite color? 2 1
What is your age? 1 1
```

In the last part...I would know what those values mean based on the query.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is well formatted. The only thing you should add is some SQL that you've tried already. SO works best when you show the attempts you've already made and let us help you on the path.

Comment: Thanks! Sure, I will include some code next time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.Question,
       t.Answer,
       COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM YourTable AS t
GROUP BY t.Question,
         t.Answer
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the second question involves `count(distinct)`:

```
select t.Question, count(distinct t.Answer) as NumAnswers,
       count(*) as NumAnswered
from table t
group by t.Question;
```

Comment: This was actually different than what I wanted...but I found out after running it that I wanted this as well! So thanks!